# Set multiple Environment variables in IISNode

Tags: node.js, configuration, iisnode

I understand I can use web.config.

```
<iisnode      
  node_env="production"
/>
```

to specify one environmental `node_env` variable which could be accessed in server side *.js files via `process.env.node_env`.

However, for example I would like to have access to another environmental variable like 
`process.env.GLOBAL_PREFIX`. Similar scenarios like access to AWS credentials.

When I tried

```
<iisnode      
  node_env="production"
  GLOBAL_PREFIX="somevalue"
/>
```

, I could not get application running due to unrecognized web.config file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IISNode exposes any keys specified in your `<appSettings>` to the `process.env` object.

If you want to access `GLOBAL_PREFIX` in your Node app just do this

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="GLOBAL_PREFIX" value="somevalue" />
  </appSettings>
```

**Server.js**

```
var globalPrefix = process.env.GLOBAL_PREFIX;
```

Comment: Can this be added to an iisnode.yml override file and it will work?